# History tracking on knowledge article standard fields

Tags: salesforcedx, knowledge, history-tracking

We are trying to enable history tracking for knowledge article and some standard/custom fields. And then push those changes into github repo.

For custom fields, it is okay to retrieve those changes. However, for standard fields, I failed to retrieve those fields into my local repository.

I have tried with

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:Knowledge__kav
```

But still only custom fields are retrieved.

So my questions are:

1. Do we actually need to worry about those field tracking? Since knowledge history is tracked based on versions instead of a related list, it should auto-track all the fields I assume?
2. If that is needed, is there a way we can retrieve them into our code base?

Comment: I have noticed this as well - I believe that SFDC MDAPI is inconsistent about returning history tracking on standard objects - it does for some, not for others. (I discovered this using Gearset). But basically, you don't care because any deployment into an org will have those standard fields/objects already enabled with history tracking